# jQuery, Dynamically generate a select list with multiple nested optgroups

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist, optgroup

Below is some of the data i have.

**Id** _ _ _ _ **ParentId** _ _**Name** _ _ _ _ _ _ _**DisplayPath**
27604 _ _NULL _ _ _ _New Zealand _ _ _ 1
26259 _ _27604 _ _ _ North Island _ _ _ _1.1
26314 _ _26259 _ _ _ Auckland _ _ _ _ _ 1.1.1
26359 _ _26259 _ _ _ Bay of Islands _ _ _1.1.2
26322 _ _26359 _ _ _ Paihia _ _ _ _ _ _ _1.1.2.1
26333 _ _26259 _ _ _ Hawkes Bay _ _ _ _1.1.3

Using jQuery i need to create a select list like the below using the data above. Any data that is a parent has to become an optgroup, whereas any data that isnt a parent ( has no children e.g. Paihia ) has to become a standard option.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="New Zealand">
    <optgroup label="North Island">
      <option value="26314">Auckland</option>
      <optgroup label="Bay Of Islands">
        <option value="26322">Paihia</option>
      </optgroup>
      <option value="26333">Hawkes Bay</option>
    </optgroup>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Am really desperate for some help on this as its for a project im currently working on.

Comment: That would be [invalid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6), JavaScript isn't going to like having to help you do that, and will break. In exciting, and unpredictable, ways.

Comment: Oh ok, i didn't think to check if that was valid as it seemed like it should be. The main reasons why I wanted the above format was so that all parent items weren't selectable and that indentation could be applied without adding spaces which then just make selected items look weird.